# problems in uninstalling anaconda after follow the suggestions on Conda website

Tags: miniconda

I am trying to uninstall miniconda from my macOS. I first followed the guidelines from the website, which is `anaconda-clean –yes`.
However, I notice that after that, I could still use the conda command, such as `which conda` and `conda info`.
Therefore I run the `conda info -a` and get the following outcomes:

```
  active environment : None
            shell level : 0
       user config file : /Users/scottxu/.condarc
 populated config files : 
          conda version : 4.9.2
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.9.1.final.0
       virtual packages : __osx=10.16=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : /opt/miniconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /opt/miniconda3/pkgs
                          /Users/scottxu/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /opt/miniconda3/envs
                          /Users/scottxu/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/4.9.2 requests/2.25.0 CPython/3.9.1 Darwin/21.3.0 OSX/10.16
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False

# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /opt/miniconda3

sys.version: 3.9.1 (default, Dec 11 2020, 06:28:49) 
...
sys.prefix: /opt/miniconda3
sys.executable: /opt/miniconda3/bin/python
conda location: /opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda
conda-build: None
conda-env: /opt/miniconda3/bin/conda-env
user site dirs: 

CIO_TEST: <not set>
CONDA_BACKUP_JAVA_HOME: :-
CONDA_BACKUP_JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH: :-
CONDA_EXE: /opt/miniconda3/bin/conda
CONDA_PYTHON_EXE: /opt/miniconda3/bin/python
CONDA_ROOT: /opt/miniconda3
CONDA_SHLVL: 0
CURL_CA_BUNDLE: <not set>
JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/miniconda3/lib/server
PATH: /opt/miniconda3/bin:/opt/miniconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE: <not set>
SSL_CERT_FILE: <not set>
```

I think this means that my uninstallation is failed, how could I delete it?
Thank you very much for your kind helps~

Answer (score 1):

You are not following the instructions on [the docs](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/) fully. After running the `anaconda-clean` command, as a last point it states to do (in your case):

```
rm -rf /opt/miniconda3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But when I try your code, I got: rm: /opt/miniconda3: Permission denied. How could I solve that? Also, at my current step, I could also get a bunch of options when I run conda -h, it seems that I didn't remove it at all?

Comment: @ScottXU No, you didn't remove it at all. Try adding sudo to the rm call